# Exercise $2.28$ Goldrei

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, alternative-proof

My question is about part $(b)-(i)$. Is there an easier way to solve it other than proving that for any truth assignment $v:Form(P,S) \rightarrow \{T,F\}$, $v^{**} = v$? thanks.

[image: ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some sense you can say that there is no simpler way, although technically you don't need the actual equality $v^{**} = v$, just that for every truth assignment $v$, there is some truth assignment $w$ such that $w^* = v$.

Expanding the definitions gives the proof:

> $φ$ is a tautology
>
> iff ( $v(φ) = T$ for every truth assignment $v$ )
>
> iff ( $v^*(φ^*) = T$ for every truth assignment $v$ )
>
> iff ( $v(φ^*) = T$ for every truth assignment $v$ )   [(1)]
>
> iff ( $φ^*$ is a tautology ).

(1) is trivial for the backward implication but uses the earlier remark for the forward implication.

Comment: thank you. Yes when I said $v^{**} = v$ I meant that I don't see how to prove existence of a such $w$ without that fact in hand

Comment: @madmatician: Indeed that's the obvious way.